# Testing Lambda NodeJS locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda

I'm trying to follow the examples found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52019039/how-to-test-aws-lambda-handler-locally-using-nodejs), but am not quite getting it.  Here is what I have:

**simpletest.js**:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log('>> Handler called');

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Handler Data')
    };

    console.log('>> Response[1]: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    return response;
};
```

**simplerun.js**

```
let process = require('./simpletest.js');

console.log(">> START");
process.handler(
  {}, // event
  {}, // context
  function(response,error) {
    console.log(">> Response[2]: " + response);
  }
);
console.log(">> END");
```

**What I got:**

```
% node simplerun.js
>> START
>> Handler called
>> Response[1]: {"statusCode":200,"body":"\"Handler Data\""}
>> END
```

**What I expected:**

```
% node simplerun.js
>> START
>> Handler called
>> Response[1]: {"statusCode":200,"body":"\"Handler Data\""}
>> Response[2]: {"statusCode":200,"body":"\"Handler Data\""}
>> END
```

Why isn't Response[2] being generated as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the handler function of `simpletest.js`, you haven't used the third parameter to call the desired callback function.

You might need to change the function to something like...

```
async (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('>> Handler called');

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Handler Data')
    };

    console.log('>> Response[1]: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    callback(response); // instead of returning, execute the callback
};
```